# How can i send a session value into sql query in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, web, frontend

When i'm sending a session value into sql query it send a NULL value.
When i manually change the value to `$userMail="abc@gmail.com"` instead of `$userMail=$_SESSION['em']` everything works fine.
Thank U for helping me :)

```
<?php
require_once("../php/db.php");

if(!isset($_SESSION['em'])) {
      $userMail = $_SESSION['em'];
  } 

$taskName = $_POST['taskName'];
$taskDate = $_POST['taskDate'];
$writerName = $_POST['writerName'];
$isDone = $_POST['isDone'];

$sql ="INSERT INTO `tasksToDo`( `taskName`, `taskDate`, `writerName` , `isDone`, `userMail`)
VALUES ('$taskName','$taskDate','$writerName','$isDone','$userMail')";
if ($conn->query($sql)===TRUE) {
    $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
    echo json_encode(array('success' => 1,"id"=>$last_id));
}else {
    echo json_encode(array('success' => 0));
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: You are doing `$userMail = $_SESSION['em']`, when `$_SESSION['em']` is _not_ set - which of course makes zero sense.

Comment: You forgot to put `session_start();` to gain access to the session. Also you're only trying to get access to the variable when it isn't set, which make no sense. And even if you'd got the boolean logic right on that, you'd then be sometimes trying to use the value when it isn't set, which also doesn't make much sense. What would you actually want to happen if the value isn't set? Should there be a default value? or null? Or just not run the query?

Comment: Thank u for your help, I understood the problems :)

Answer (score 1):

Tnx to CBroe and ADyson, the solution is:

```
<?php session_start();
require_once("../php/db.php");
if(!isset($_SESSION['em'])){ // if the user is not logged in then don't enter the system
    header('Location: logIn.php');
    exit;
}
if(isset($_SESSION['em'])) {
    $userMail =$_SESSION['em'];

} 


$taskName = $_POST['taskName'];
$taskDate = $_POST['taskDate'];
$writerName = $_POST['writerName'];
$isDone = $_POST['isDone'];

$sql ="INSERT INTO `tasksToDo`( `taskName`, `taskDate`, `writerName` , `isDone`, `userMail`)
VALUES ('$taskName','$taskDate','$writerName','$isDone','$userMail')";
if ($conn->query($sql)===TRUE) {
    $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
    echo json_encode(array('success' => 1,"id"=>$last_id));
}else {
    echo json_encode(array('success' => 0));
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: You still need to urgently fix the SQL injection vulnerability as well though. Not to mention that I could break your query just by typing a `'` (apostrophe) into one of your fields. What if the writer's surname is `O'Brien`? :-) Parameterised queries fix both those issues.

Comment: Also this still doesn't address another problem I mentioned...what if the Session variable is not set? Then $userMail will be undefined, but your program will still go ahead and try to use it in the query anyway. What do you expect to happen in that case? For that matter, your code doesn't try to check if any of the $_POST variables are set either, so if any of them are missing you could have problems too.